# Tweaking a dropdown pricelist by adding custom variable fields etc. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, forms, quotes, price

Hello this is a pricelist dropdown. What I wanted to know is how to add some custom values and some dropdown values that will multiply the outcome and add to the total price. Name it index.js Below is the javascript:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

function updatePrice(select) {
  jQuery(select).parent().siblings('.price').html('$' + select.value);

  var sum = 0;
  jQuery('.price').each(function(){
    PlgContentPricetable = jQuery(this).text().toString().replace('$', '');
    sum = Number(parseFloat( PlgContentPricetable )) + sum;
  });
  jQuery('.total').html('$' + Number(sum).toFixed(2) );

}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var html = '';
  html += '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="pricingTable">';
  html += '<thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Options</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>';

  jQuery('#pricingTable > li').each(function(){
    var item = jQuery(this).find('h4').text();

    var select = '<select onchange="updatePrice(this);">';
    select += '<option value="0.00">Select</option>';
    jQuery(this).find('ul > li').each(function(){
      var price = jQuery(this).text().match(/\$\S+/g);
      select += '<option value="' + price.toString().replace('$', '') + '">' + jQuery(this).text() + '</option>';
    });
    select += '</select>';
    html += '<tr><td><strong>' + item + '</strong></td><td>' + select + '</td><td class="price">$0.00</td></tr>';
  });

  if(jQuery('#basePrice').val() != ''){
    jQuery('#basePrice').hide();
    html += '<tr><td colspan="2" align="right">Setup Charge and Test Pressing</td><td class="price">$' + jQuery('#basePrice').val() + '</td></tr>';
  }

  html += '<tfoot><tr><td colspan="2" align="right">Total</td><td class="total">$' + jQuery('#basePrice').val() + '</td></tr></tfoot></table></div>';

  jQuery('#pricingTable').replaceWith(html);

});
```

Now for the html I am using. Quantity should be a custom field that you enter a variable amount. It must multiply the prices and dropdown options according to the amount entered. Another issue is that the Weight and Color tabs should also change the total price accordingly but must stay as dropdown menus. When you select the option the total changes depending on your selection but also from the quantity amount... Please Help I'm in a mess!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Maiko Rekords</title>



    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">




  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
<ul id="pricingTable">
  <li>
    <h4>Quantity</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>300pcs $183.00</li>
      <li>500pcs $305.00</li>
      <li>1000pcs $610.00</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<li>
    <h4>Size</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>7" Vinyl $330.00</li>
      <li>10" Vinyl $550.00</li>
      <li>12" Vinyl $1,100.00</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Weight</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>120gr $183.00</li>
      <li>150gr $305.00</li>
      <li>180gr $610.00</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<li>
    <h4>Color</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Black $0.00</li>
      <li>Transparent $0.00</li>
      <li>Single Color $417.00</li>
      <li>Two Color $417.00</li>
      <li>Three Color $417.00</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

<p><input id="basePrice" type="text" value="170.00" placeholder="Black Vinyl" /></p>

</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if I can explain more what is my problem.